# Could not evaluate: [/dev/null]:is an invalid url

Tags: puppet

I am automating an instance using Puppet in Google Compute engine. I installed necessary gcloud tool and running the manifest file using "`puppet apply new-ins.pp`" but not able to execute successfully as I am getting an error

> Could not evaluate: [/dev/null]: is an invalid un
>
> Could not evaluate: Invalid line 3: url[/dev/null]:

What exactly I need to put in `device.conf`

File `new-ins.pp`:

```
gce_instance { 'puppet-test':  
  ensure       => present,
  description  => 'A Puppet test',
  machine_type => 'n1-standard-1',
  zone         => 'us-central1-a',
  network      => 'default',
  image        => 'projects/centos-cloud/global/images/centos-6-v20131120',
  tags         => ['puppet', 'pp-master'],
  startupscript        => 'puppet-enterprise.sh',
  metadata             => {
    'pe_role'          => 'master',
    'pe_version'       => '3.3.1',
    'pe_consoleadmin'  => 'arunp7080@gmail.com',
    'pe_consolepwd'    => 'puppetize',
  },
  service_account_scopes => ['compute-ro'],
}
```

That's the output I get:

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Gce_instance[puppet-test]: Could not evaluate: Invalid line 3:   url[/dev/null]: 

/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/network_device/config.rb:65:in `parse'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/network_device/config.rb:44:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/network_device/config.rb:44:in `parse'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/network_device/config.rb:42:in `open'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/network_device/config.rb:42:in `parse'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/network_device/config.rb:33:in `read'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/network_device/config.rb:26:in `initiali
```

Comment: Could you paste the content of `new-ins.pp` ?

Comment: Paste is to your question and format it properly.

Comment: I am not able to format it properly, I'll check the instructions.

Comment: I have modified my question, can you see it ?? Also removed the answer.

Comment: Can you add `--trace` to your `puppet apply`? If this yields stack traces, please share them.

Comment: I get some messages using "--trace", shall I paste it in comment ??

Comment: Oh god no! :) Please use pastebin and add the link to your question.

Comment: Pasted. Let me know if any other things are to be done on my end.

Comment: Something about managing networking, then. Are you sure that `network => 'default'` is a valid and correct setting in your environment? - Note, please use @<name> in comments so that we get notified of your updates.

Comment: @FelixFrank ... I have no idea which environment are you referring as i have set something in "device.conf" and just applying the manifest, I am not sure of the settings as this is first time I am automating google instances.

Comment: @user3933150 I can't tell you more either. I never used GCE myself, much less the module. I can only advise to make sure that your settings are consistent.

Comment: @FelixFrank: pasteboards are OK if the output is excessively long, but otherwise we don't want much of a dependence upon them. Links do break, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this issue myself.  It seems like there is additional URI validation starting from Puppet 3.7.5

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/3.7.5/lib/puppet/util/network_device/config.rb#L86

To work with this, I've temporarily commented out the validation rule in the local version...

Comment: Thanks a lot... I got my instance in running state :)

Comment: @user3933150
Can I have a syntax about how to define class inside a manifest file??
I included on the top.